# When using Newton-Raphson's method for a given function, how do I estimate the asymptotic convergence factor?

Tags: convergence-divergence, newton-raphson

I have a function $f(x)$ and I calculated iterations until I got the root.

I have proven that it has quadratic convergence.

However, I am now asked to estimate the asymptotic convergence factor.

This is the factor K that relates the error between each iteration, is it not?

$K= \max \frac{f''(x)}{2 \min f'(x)}$?

When doing so, however, I got a K=60, which would mean that with each iteration, the error would greatly increasy which doesn't make sense given that it converges so quickly.

Comment: The quantity $K$ is used in the proof of *local* quadratic convergence as a bound that simply appears in the proof to rule out an indeterminate scenario. It is not indicative of the actual convergence rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have shown $f(x)$ converges quadratically,  then you have shown that there exists a finite $K$ such that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|\varepsilon_{n+1}|}{\varepsilon_n^2} = $K$
$$
Here, $\varepsilon_n$ stands for the error in the $n$-th guess.

If you have shown that it converges quadratically but no faster, then your $K > 0$.

$K$ is the asymptotic convergence factor.

Example:  Say $f(x) = x^2-1$.
Then if $x_k = 1+\varepsilon_k$, 
$$
x_{k+1} = 1+\varepsilon_k-\frac{(1+\varepsilon_k)^2-1}{2(1+\varepsilon_k)} 
=1+\frac12\varepsilon_k^2+O(\varepsilon_k^3)\\
\varepsilon_{k+1}=\frac12\varepsilon_k^2+O(\varepsilon_k^3) \\
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|\varepsilon_{n+1}|}{\varepsilon_n^2} = \frac12
$$
so for this function, NR converges quadratically with an asymptotic convergence factor of $\frac12$.

Of course, for this simple function you can get the closed form value of the $n$-th guess given some starting guess, as an expression involving hyperbolic tangents and arctangetns and $2^n$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x_{n}\rightarrow x^{\star}$. If we can write
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\left|x_{n+1}-x^{\star}\right|}{\left|x_{n}-x^{\star}\right|^{r}}=L
$$
for $0<L<\infty$ and $r\geq1$, we call $r$ the rate of convergence.
An approximation of this is given by
$$
r\approx\frac{\log\left|\left(x_{n+1}-x_{n}\right)/\left(x_{n}-x_{n-1}\right)\right|}{\log\left|\left(x_{n}-x_{n-1}\right)/\left(x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}\right)\right|}.
$$
See [this document](http://www.math-cs.gordon.edu/courses/ma342/handouts/rate.pdf) for a gentle introduction.

Comment: thank you for your response! however, is rate of convergence the same as asymptotic convergence factor?

Comment: I believe so. Mark has given an even better answer above.

Comment: Yes he has. Thank you anyways for your input!